# Google Maps Autocomplete

Tags: ios, swift

Within my Swift iOS app, I am using this library to show Google Place auto complete: https://github.com/watsonbox/ios_google_places_autocomplete

This is what I have in my main view controller:

```
let gpaViewController = GooglePlacesAutocomplete(
  apiKey: "myapikey",
  placeType: .Address
)

gpaViewController.placeDelegate = self // Conforms to GooglePlacesAutocompleteDelegate

presentViewController(gpaViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This works well, but it takes me to a new view. How do I apply the autocomplete on a search field in my main view controller without having to switch over to another view?

Comment: Do you still need an Autocomplete method? I could provide an answer for you if you need.

Answer (score 2):

Hey use this swift code from GitHub

https://github.com/vijayvir/LeoGoogle/blob/master/AutoCompeteWithSearchBar/LeoGoogleAutoCompleteSearch.swift

```
@IBOutlet var leoGoogleAutoCompleteSearch: LeoGoogleAutoCompleteSearch!
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
leoGoogleAutoCompleteSearch.closureDidUpdateSearchBarWithPredictions = { predictions in

predictions.map({ (prediction ) -> Void in

print(prediction.placeId ?? "NG" , "        " , prediction.description ?? "NG" )

})

}
```

Here I have made the object of autocomplete  api which will return the place_id and description of the search through closure  . further  Developer can modify the code . For request I have use Almofire for get reguest , which is common these days .

more about code

```
mport Foundation
import GooglePlaces
import Alamofire
import UIKit
typealias LeoGoogleMapACompletionBlock = (AnyObject, AnyObject) -> Void

typealias LeoGoogleMapAFailureBlock = (AnyObject, AnyObject) -> Void

struct LeoGoogleMapsApiPlaceAutocomplete {
    static func get(url: URL,
                   completionHandler: LeoGoogleMapACompletionBlock? = nil,
                   failureHandler: LeoGoogleMapAFailureBlock? = nil) {
        print(" get :", url)

        Alamofire.request(url,
                          method: .get
            )
            .responseJSON { response in

                print(" get  " )

                if let json = response.result.value {

                    //  print("WebServices : - ", json)
                    completionHandler!(json as AnyObject, response.result as AnyObject)

                } else {

                    failureHandler?("" as AnyObject, "" as AnyObject)

                }

            }
            .responseString { _ in

                failureHandler?("" as AnyObject, "" as AnyObject)

                //  print("responseString Success: \(responseString)")
            }
            .responseData { _ in
        }
    }



    struct Prediction {
        var description : String?
        var id : String?
        var placeId : String?
        init(dictionary : NSDictionary) {
            description = dictionary["description"] as? String
            id = dictionary["id"] as? String
            placeId = dictionary["place_id"] as? String
        }
    }
    var predictions: [Prediction] = []
    init(response: AnyObject) {
        if let searchList = response["predictions"] as? [Any] {
            for object in searchList {
                let tempPrediction = Prediction(dictionary: (object as? NSDictionary)!)
                predictions.append(tempPrediction)
            }
        }
    }
}
class LeoGoogleAutoCompleteSearch: NSObject {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    var closureDidUpdateSearchBar : ((LeoGoogleMapsApiPlaceAutocomplete)-> Void)?
    var closureDidUpdateSearchBarWithPredictions : (([LeoGoogleMapsApiPlaceAutocomplete.Prediction])-> Void)?

}
extension LeoGoogleAutoCompleteSearch : UISearchBarDelegate  {
    func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    func searchBarShouldEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {

        return true }
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) { // called when text changes (including clear)
        webserviceSearchBy(text: searchBar.text!)
    }
    func webserviceSearchBy(text : String) {

        let newString = text.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")

        let url : URL = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=\(newString)&key=AIzaSyAVrXmSPxYourApiPK_ceurWlZJgrpWY")!

        LeoGoogleMapsApiPlaceAutocomplete.get(url: url, completionHandler: { (response, _) in
            let some  : LeoGoogleMapsApiPlaceAutocomplete = LeoGoogleMapsApiPlaceAutocomplete(response: response)
            self.closureDidUpdateSearchBar?(some)
            self.closureDidUpdateSearchBarWithPredictions?(some.predictions)

        }) { (response, _) in

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these two variables ...

`let autoPlaceURLString : String = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json"`

`let apiKey = "your api key"`

Now Set your UITextfield delegate to self. And on textfield change method call this below method...

`fetchAutocompletePlaces(keyword: textField.text!)`

You will receive an array of addresses...

```
func fetchAutocompletePlaces(keyword: String) {

    let urlString = "\(autoPlaceURLString)?key=\(apiKey)&input=\(keyword)"
    let s = (CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed as NSCharacterSet).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableCharacterSet
    s.addCharacters(in: "+&")
    let encodedURL = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: s as CharacterSet)

    Alamofire.request(encodedURL!).responseJSON { (response) in

        if response.result.isSuccess {
            if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                let predictions = json["predictions"]
                var locations = [String]()
                for dict in predictions as! [NSDictionary]{
                    locations.append(dict["description"] as! String)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    self.strAddressByGoogle = locations
                    if (self.strAddressByGoogle.count == 0){
                        self.tblAddress.isHidden = true
                    }else {
                        self.tblAddress.isHidden = false
                    }
                    self.tblAddress.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now show this list in a UITableView on the same view.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use Google Places API for iOS ? and follow the steps to do it in programmatically using fetcher. Link : https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically